# Extarrow-column

Tags: arrows

I would like to ask you if there is a better way to write this code `\begin{matrix*}\xrightarrow[something]{something}\vspace{-2mm}\\\xrightarrow[something]{}\end{matrix*}`  and if there is a way to create `n` arrows (`\xrightarrow`s, `\xleftarrow`s, `\xleftrightarrow`s or any extensible arrows) arranged in a column.

Sorry, I forgot to mention that I would like to can choose how to align the arguments of the arrows, (`[r]`, `[l]`, `[c]`). Also, I would like the arrows to have the same length and I would like to know if there is a way to customize the length of the arrows and the alignment of the arguments.

I state that I know the `extarrows` package.

Comment: Ok, but how? I do not know very well tikz. What is the code? Thank you in advanced

Comment: Could you provide a sketch of the expected result?

Comment: Eh I'm new here ... I do not know how do...

Comment: A free-hand drawing would suffice

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say that this is any better, but it is certainly a lot more flexible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\newlength{\mathbase}% distance from center to baseline
\setlength{\mathbase}{\dimexpr 0.5\dp\strutbox-0.5\ht\strutbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*} x=
\begin{matrix}
  \xrightarrow[something]{something}\vspace{-2mm}\\
  \xrightarrow[something]{}
\end{matrix}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*} x= 
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(base), font=\scriptsize, inner xsep=1pt]
\matrix (A) [matrix of math nodes] {something \\ something \\ something \\};
\coordinate[yshift=\mathbase] (base) at (A.center);
\path (A-1-1) -- (A-2-1) coordinate[midway] (A12);% between rows 1 and 2
\path (A-2-1) -- (A-3-1) coordinate[midway] (A23);% between rows 2 and 3
\draw[->] (A.west |- A12) -- (A.east |- A12);
\draw[->] (A.west |- A23) -- (A.east |- A23);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

---

Will this do?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\newlength{\mathbase}% distance from center to baseline
\setlength{\mathbase}{\dimexpr 0.5\dp\strutbox-0.5\ht\strutbox}

\newcommand{\twoarrows}[3]{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(base), font=\scriptsize, inner xsep=1pt]
  \matrix (A) [matrix of math nodes] {{#1}\\{#2}\\{#3}\\};
  \coordinate[yshift=\mathbase] (base) at (A.center);
  \path (A-1-1) -- (A-2-1) coordinate[midway] (A12);% between rows 1 and 2
  \path (A-2-1) -- (A-3-1) coordinate[midway] (A23);% between rows 2 and 3
  \draw[->] (A.west |- A12) -- (A.east |- A12);
  \draw[->] (A.west |- A23) -- (A.east |- A23);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
 x= \twoarrows{first}{second}{third}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I try to explain myself even better. Given a vector of `n` components, I would like that vector to be split into `n-1` rows. That is, I would like a `\begin{array}{c} something \\ \hline something \\ \hline \vdots \\ \hline something \end{array}` with a `\xrightarrow` instead of `\hline`. And I would like this `\xrightarrow` to extend to the maximum width of the array. It's possible? Thank you

Comment: Except for the "somethings" being the rows and the arrows being between the rows, no problem.  Just add more rows as needed.

Comment: Maybe I did not say it clear enough. I meant that I wanted `\xrightarrow` type extendable arrows instead of `\hlines`.

Comment: Could I, if desired, create a `\newcommand` of the type `\newcommand{\hrightarrow}{\xrightarrow instead of \hline, but I don't know how to write it in LaTeX}`? Could you please help me? Thank you very much.